# Connections between Levy Processes and Exponential Families

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

Let $\{\mathbb{P}_{\theta}\}_{\theta}$ be an exponential family of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with
$$
\frac{d\mathbb{P}_{\theta}}{d\mathbb{P}} \propto \exp\left(
\sum_{n=1}^N \eta_n(\theta) S_n(x)
\right),
$$
where $S_n:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are its sufficient statistics.

Let $(X_t)$ be the Levy process with increments distributed according to this exponential family.  Can we say anything about its Levy-Khintchine representation?